# bind radio buttons with slider angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bind

Im trying to bind these radio buttons with the slider using angularjs. if the user chooses the radio centimeters radio button, then the slider should move dynamically to 10 and the textbox display 10, if pixels is chosen to 1 and so on. and it should start at 1(pixels)by default.

```js
"use strict";

// Creates the "backend" logical support for appMyExample
var myModule = angular.module("appMyExample", []);

// define a function to create a new slider at locID (expected to be a div)
var createSlider = function (locID, label, guiModel) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(locID);
    elm.innerHTML = "<b>" + label + "</b><br>";
    elm.innerHTML += "Bar : <input type='range' min=\"1\" max='50' ng-model='" + guiModel + "'>";
    elm.innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model='" + guiModel + "' size='1'>";
};

// Now, call the GUI creation functions 

createSlider("idLeft", "LeftSlider", "mLeftModel");


myModule.controller("exCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.mLeftModel = "1";
});
```

```html
<body >
        <div ng-app="appMyExample" ng-controller="exCtrl" >
          <p><b>Unit:</b><input name='rad' type="radio" > Pixels (1)
                    <input name='rad' type="radio" > Millimeters (5)
                    <input name='rad' type="radio" > Centimeters (10)
                    <input name='rad' type="radio" > Meters (50)
          </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="idLeft" style="outline: 2px solid"> </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <label>    Total displacement:    <input type="text" value="{{mLeftModel}}" ></label>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `ng-change` for radio and based on that reinitialized your slider.

Don't forget to specify the `ng-value` to the radio button.

```js
"use strict";

// Creates the "backend" logical support for appMyExample
var myModule = angular.module("appMyExample", []);

// define a function to create a new slider at locID (expected to be a div)
var createSlider = function (locID, label, guiModel) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(locID);
    elm.innerHTML = "<b>" + label + "</b><br>";
    elm.innerHTML += "Bar : <input type='range' min=\"1\" max='"+guiModel+"' ng-model='" + guiModel + "'>";
    //elm.innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model='" + guiModel + "' size='1'>";
};
myModule.controller("exCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.flag = 1;
    createSlider("idLeft", "LeftSlider", $scope.flag);
  
    $scope.changeSlider = function(flag){
      createSlider("idLeft", "LeftSlider", flag);
    };
});
```

```html
<body >
        <div ng-app="appMyExample" ng-controller="exCtrl" >
          <p><b>Unit:</b><input name='rad' ng-model="flag" type="radio" ng-value="1" ng-change="changeSlider(1)"> Pixels (1)
                    <input name='rad' ng-model="flag" type="radio" ng-value="5" ng-change="changeSlider(5)"> Millimeters (5)
                    <input name='rad' ng-model="flag" type="radio" ng-value="10" ng-change="changeSlider(10)"> Centimeters (10)
                    <input name='rad' ng-model="flag" type="radio" ng-value="50" ng-change="changeSlider(50)"> Meters (50)
          </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="idLeft" style="outline: 2px solid"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <label>    Total displacement:    <input type="text" value="{{flag}}" ></label>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `select` is more suitable, check box is good at true/false things.

and use ng-model to do two way data binding.

I change your code to do what you want, but it is just a example for you. :-)

```js
"use strict";

// Creates the "backend" logical support for appMyExample
var myModule = angular.module("appMyExample", []);

// define a function to create a new slider at locID (expected to be a div)
var createSlider = function (locID, label, guiModel) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(locID);
    elm.innerHTML = "<b>" + label + "</b><br>";
    elm.innerHTML += "Bar : <input type='range' min=\"1\" max='50' ng-model=\"mLeftModel\">";
    elm.innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model=\"mLeftModel\" size='1'>";
};

// Now, call the GUI creation functions 

createSlider("idLeft", "LeftSlider", "mLeftModel");


myModule.controller("exCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.mLeftModel = "1";
});
```

```html
<body >
        <div ng-app="appMyExample" ng-controller="exCtrl" >
          <p><b>Unit:</b>
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="mLeftModel">
      <option value="1">Pixels (1)</option>
      <option value="5">Millimeters (5)</option>
<option value="10">Centimeters (10)</option>
<option value="50">Meters (50)</option>
    </select>
          </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="idLeft" style="outline: 2px solid"> </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <label>    Total displacement:    <input type="text" value="{{mLeftModel}}" ng-model="mLeftModel"></label>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```